# How to download code of latest Linux kernel From development branch of Linux kernel maintainers?

Tags: linux-kernel

I Want latest code of Linux kernel as latest patches or feature merged in Linux kernel.I wonder if i can get latest kernel code through rsync or git source ?

I don't want stable code , even if code is not compiling completely.  that's OK.

Comment: Linux is big enough to not have a *single* development branch (but many branches). But you could download something from http://kernel.org/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, JFYI: there is a mostly daily-based collection of those called *linux-next* tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you need *linux-next* tree which is accessible from [site of Linux kernel](http://www.kernel.org)

So, you need to add a specific remote to existing clone of Linux tree (you may also consider [how to manage many trees at one host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133140/cascaded-git-repositories-socs-linux-kernel/34141545#34141545))

```
git remote add next git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git
git remote update next
```

or run a new clone operation:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git
```